# How to echo a clickable thumbnail of a link using custom post & custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I want to add a clickable thumbnail to my search engine:
http://worldpronet.site/index.php/2-2/
What I want to get is this:
https://snipboard.io/HYVtEq.jpg
1. I am using Custom Post Type UI (CPT UI) plugin to form 'GBO' post type.
1. I am using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin to form a field type URL with these parameters:
- Meta-key data-key="field_5dbbe149495af"
- id="acf-field_5dbbe149495af" name="acf[field_5dbbe149495af]"
- the URL is https://www.worldpronet.com/professional-network/victoria-zheng/"

I have already added the link to GBO post using the URL meta-box of ACF and now I would like to echo a clickable thumbnail in the table.

I want to add the new code to the index.PHP that will show victoria zheng clickable thumbnail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Sao, for your grammar suggestions.